# Поиск подстроки в std::vector<string>

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, vector

Подскажите как решить следующую задачу оптимальным путем:

есть std::vector stringVector, содержащий 3 элемента.

Есть задача:

Найти, содержит ли i-ый элемент stringVector подстроку(std::string).

Пример:

Допустим, stringVector состоит из:

stringVector[0] = "Сегодня хороший день.";

stringVector[1] = "Завтра будет день апокалипсиса.";

stringVector[2] = "Привет, Андрей.";

string searchString = "день";

То, что я написал(но не работает):

```
        for (size_t i = 0;  i < tokens.size(); i++)
        {
            // Не работает: ошибка бинарный оператор == не найден и т.д. 
            auto result = find(tokens[i].begin(), tokens[i].end(), searchString);
            if (result != tokens[i].end())
            {
                // Какое-то действие
            }
        }
```

P.s. я бы мог сделать перегрузку оператора == в глобальной области(или достаточно в области видимости класса?) для моего случая и объявить его дружественным классу, но не понимаю какие аргументы он должен принимать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите что-то такое?

```
vector<string> tokens;
string sub;

....

for(const auto& s: tokens)
    if (s.find(sub)!=s.npos)
    {
        // Найдена подстрока
    }
```

Comment: почти так. Но можно ли как-то сделать, что поиск осуществлялся по конкретному tokens[i]? То есть когда итерируется цикл for, поиск должен происходить не во всех tokens, как у Вас в примере, а только в tokens[i]?

Comment: спасибо! Ваш вариант натолкнул мою пустую голову на правильное решение!